# AS/400: Most efficient DB2 SQL to unpack EBCDIC subfield values as strings?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, ebcdic

Most files I am working with only have the following fields:

- F00001 - usually 1 (f1) or 9 (f9)
- K00001 - usually only 1-3 sub-fields of
  zoned decimals and ebcdic
- F00002 - sub-fields of ebcdic, zoned and
  packed decimals

Occasionally other field names K00002, F00003 and F00004 will appear in cross reference files.

**Example Data:**

```
+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| F00001  | K00001                                           |  F00002                                                                                    |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| f1      |  f0  f0  f0  f0  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  d7  c8  | e2  e3  c1  c3  d2  d6  e5  c5  d9  c6  d3  d6  e7  40 12  34  56  7F  e2  d2  c5  c5  e3  |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Currently using:**

```
SELECT SUBSTR(HEX(F00001), 1, 2) AS FNAME_1, SUBSTR(HEX(K00001), 1, 14) AS KNAME_1, SUBSTR(HEX(K00001), 15, 2) AS KNAME_2, SUBSTR(HEX(K00001), 17, 2) AS KNAME_2, SUBSTR(HEX(F00002), 1, 28) AS FNAME_2, SUBSTR(HEX(F00002), 29, 8) AS FNAME_3, SUBSTR(HEX(F00002), 37, 10) AS FNAME_4 FROM QS36F.FILE
```

Is this the best way to unpack EBCDIC values as strings?

Comment: All of that can be taken care of automatically if you a) set a proper ccsid (37) and b) externally describe the tables.  Trying to convert ebcdic, and unpack zoned and packed decimals is a fools errand.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe it is a fool's errand. There are header rows in files that have different layouts and lengths than the others in the same file. Wouldn't three DDS' for one file be redundant?

Comment: It would be like trying to parse a Microsoft SQL Server database by reading the .MDF file directly.  However if you are dealing with a multi-record-type physical file you have no choice.

Comment: What you have shown are all zoned decimal.

Comment: @WarrenT If you are to use the horizontal scroll bar in my table sample you will see a field of ebcdic, a packed decimal and then more ebcdic. So my question is, if using SQL what is the best way to parse the substrings. Substring of Hex works but it feels dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for 'the best way'.  Manually fiddling the bytes is categorically NOT the best way.  @JamesA has a better answer: Externally describe the table and use more traditional SQL to access it.  I see in your comments that you have multiple layouts within the same table.  This was typical years ago when we converted from punched cards to disk.  I feel your pain, having experienced this many times.

If you are using SQL to run queries, I think you have several options, all of which revolve around having a sane DB2 table instead of a jumbled S/36 flat file.  Without more details on the business problem, all we can do is offer suggestions.

1) Add a trigger to QS36F.FILE that will break out the intermingled records into separate SQL defined tables.  Query those.

2) Write some UDFs that will pack and unpack numbers.  If you're querying today, you'll be updating tomorrow and if you think you have some chance of maintaining the raw HEX(this) and HEX(that) for SELECTS, wait until you try to do an UPDATE that way.

3) Write stored procedures that will extract out the bits you need for a given query, put them into SQL tables - maybe even a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE.  Have the SP query those bits and return a result set that can be consumed by other SQL queries.  IBM i supports user defined table functions as well.

4) Have the RPG team write you a conversion program that will read the old file and create a data warehouse that you can query against.

Comment: You and I have the same idea about everything revolving around a "sane" database table. I will look into the first option. Parts of the second and third option you listed is what I am going for. I will look deeper into option 3. Coincidentally you are the one who informed me how to UPDATE using hexadecimal literals. Option four unfortunately doesn't exist any longer as the company who provided us the original distribution software has dissolved. I would certainly be new to RPG but overall not new to programming. I am working toward a sane medium that provides data for external systems.

Comment: With packed decimal, it's theoretically possible to have 110 unique values for each byte.  Imagine a number 000.  Takes 2 bytes when packed: 00 0f.  Increment: 00 1f, 00 2f, etc and you can see that the last byte has 10 unique values, between 0f and 9f.  The other bytes in the packed decimal field can cycle from 00 through 99, which is 100 more unique values that you'd have to pack and unpack.  In RPG, the compiler does all this work - in your case, based on the I- and O-specifications in the RPG programs.  For very old applications, tables were described by the programs, not the database.

Comment: I see what you are implying and acknowledge what I have failed to explain. I have an emulation of data descriptions as the 1981 documentation I have access to is incomplete at best. There's about 1100 rows I have compiled. Example columns: table name, field name, sub-field name, start position, length, data type (ebcdic, zoned, packed), format (character, decimal, integer, date), format (MMDDYY0F, MMDDYY, CYMD, MMYY, 2 decimal places, 3 decimal places, constraints, etc.). So when I wrote 48 distinct values I really meant EBCDIC characters not zoned and packed data. Regards.

Comment: If you acknowledge my end goal of having data from the AS/400 system feed external systems (websites, intranet, etc.) you should see why I have done this and it compares well to option 3 that you listed in the accepted answer but is not the exact same. It has other columns too. Think of it as a Rosetta-like piece of information. This is why the DB2 SQL Syntax is important. I will be generating SQL syntax from the info I have compiled and redirecting the transcoded output elsewhere. HEX() fits the bill and works -think about it- but isn't used the exact way it was intended. Looking for better.

Comment: Ran across an interesting scenario. File "SH.TBLS" has 163 rows and 10 different descriptions. Laughed out loud.

Comment: There may be another way to document the database.  As an RPG programmer, the first place I would look is the RPG program source.  Typically, it is stored in files named QRPGSRC.  There should be a green screen interface called PDM.  STRPDM should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks as if old S/36 files are being accessed and the system runs under CCSID 65535. That could cause the messy "hex"representation issue as well as at least some of the column name issues. A little more info about the server environment would be useful.